# How to prevent images from being dropped into an attributable UITextView

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

I have a UITextView that supports editing text attributes like so:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    }
```

I only intended for text to be formatted for bold, italics, underline, font, text size etc., however images can also be dragged and dropped into this UITextView.

How do I restrict a UITextView to containing text only while also staying attributable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I made a text drop delegate and cancelled all text drop proposals like so:

```
func textDroppableView(_ textDroppableView: UIView & UITextDroppable, proposalForDrop drop: UITextDropRequest) -> UITextDropProposal {
    return UITextDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
}
```